# function checking string of characters and changing them

Tags: javascript

im looking for a loop that will check a string of characters for capital letters using

```
function isUpperCase(aCharacter)
{
    return (aCharacter >= 'A') && (aCharacter <= 'Z');
}
```

When the capital letter is encountered it will carry out anoter function, let's call it `'dummyFunction'`, which will change all letters to same letter as the capital letter but only until next capital letter is encountered and so on.(I hope you will understand what i mean) For example, if I would have a string 'AbcdeFghijKlmno' the outcome of the program would be: 'AAAAAFFFFFKKKKK'. Any ideas?

Comment: Your example contradicts your description. So what you want? Uppercase the entire string or uppercase only between the first uppercase character up until the next in a given string or you need examples of both?

Comment: Sorry, i only want letters between last uppercase and next changed. so all letters after A changed to A, all letters after F changed to F and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the result should copy the characters until the first capital is reached, so:

```
var wierdStringThing = (function() {
  var re = /[A-Z]/;
  return function (s) {
    s = s.split('');
    var result = [];
    var t = s[0];
    var c;

    for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      c = s[i];
      if (re.test(c)) {
        t = c;
        result.push(c);
      } else {
        // Copies characters until first capital,
        // then repeats capital until next
        result.push(re.test(t)? t : c);
      }
    }
    return result.join('');
  }
}());

var x = 'adbCasdfHasdV'
alert(x + '\n' + wierdStringThing(x));
/*
adbCasdfHasdV
adbCCCCCHHHHV
*/
```